# Difference between \baselinestretch, and \doublespacing in the setspace package

Tags: spacing, line-spacing

Am I wrong in thinking that there is a difference between the doublespacing options of `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}` and the `\doublespacing` option in the setspace package?

The code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-1]    

\end{document}
```

Produces this outcome:
[image]

Whereas

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-1]    

\end{document}
```

Gives me this:

[image]

Maybe this is a silly question but I have at least not found an obvious explanation for this difference. Which one is the 'correct' way of doublespacing? I understand the advantages of using setspace generally so I would naturally prefer this over changing the baselinestretch.

Comment: The correct approach is to use `setspace`, I think there is an explanation somewhere why `\doublespacing` isn't the same as `\renewcommand\baselinestretch{2}` (something about different definitions of line spacing, e.g. in Word linespread of 1.5 isn't the same as `\onehalfspacing`, too), but I didn't find it just now. If you need more spacing than `\doublespacing` you can use `\setstretch{2}` or similar.

Comment: I see, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\doublespacing` does not correspond to `\setstretch{2}`, as you can see in the package code, probably  because of optical effects which depend on the font size.

Namely, for the default 10pt size, it uses `\setstretch{1.667}`. For  11 pt, it is  `\setstretch{1.618}` and for 12pt, `\setstretch{1.655}`.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! It does make me wonder why `\doublespacing` is 'sold' as the usual doublespace corresponding to similar settings in Word etc. especially given certain formatting requirements made by people who are normally used to Word.

Comment: @Nilsi because Word is about ugly typesetting :)

Comment: Double spacing is a switch on a typewriter.  Trying to make typesetting pretend to be a typewriter is just sad.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I find Word and huge line spaces as horrible as you do, I was just surprised/confused :)